# How to put the equations numbers below the equation

Tags: numbers, latex, equation

I am new to LaTeX and I need to write a report, however our Professor demands very strict restriction on the template of our file.

One of them is that when we write an equation, the number be right under it, like this :

```
E = mc^2
(1)
```

rather than

```
E = mc^2              (1)
```

(Which is the default if I'm not mistaken)

Is there an easy way to force it to go down below the equation?